# ASP.NET Worker process getting killed when web app is inactive

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, keep-alive, worker-process

My hosted ASP.NET MVC app takes long time (10-20 secs) when it launches. And after ASP.NET worker process is running, everything is normal. Problem is that the worker process is getting killed when the web site is inactive (i.e., no user). This will give the next user very long wait time to load the web site.

I know there is commercial or free services on the web that makes your web worker process alive. But I need to do that myself with simple timer windows service. No problem there. But my question is what is effective way to makes it alive? Would a simple ping do it or is downloading from the web site necessary?

Comment: What version of IIS are you using?  Do you have permissions to edit the app pools, and if so, have you tried that?

Comment: No as it's hosted web site, I don't have permission to edit app pools. That's the cause of my question.

Comment: I figured it probably was, but you've gotta ask on SO :)

Comment: BTW - can you provide any details on why the existing services don't fill your need?

Comment: @arootbeer there can be many reasons but I can say this can be done in 1 hour and result in flexible intervals without spending money.

Comment: I can see the ease of creating it yourself, and the flexibility in configuration, but since you mentioned free services I was curious.  Thanks for the insight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend you set up an empty aspx page on the site and see if requesting it occasionally will fulfill your requirement.  You should only have to make a request to keep the worker alive.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't really create empty.aspx page but selected "small" page for ping action.